# Checking Collisions In 2D Platformer With Tiles

Tags: c++, 2d, collision

My team and I are developing a 2D platformer with C++/SDL/OpenGL, and we already defined a collision system, but we have a problem checking collisions with the tilemap.

The tiles of the tilemap are 32x32, so we try to define that the max speed in X and Y of the player it's less than 32 because in this case we found the problem that if the speed it's bigger than the tile size, when checking the collisions the position it's updated with the speed which it's more than 32, so in that case, the position skip a tile which causes a huge problem for verification, so at the momento we limit the X and Y speed to 30, but we don't know how make the speed bigger than the tile size without losing the complete collision detection with some possible tiles that may be skiped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sweep tests](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3383/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php?print=1).

Basically instead of simple box/box collisions you need to check for collisions between your stationary level geometry boxes and the shape formed by moving your mobile box through (position) to (position+velocity).

Comment: So, you say that instead of moving the box before the checking, during the collision checking update the position only if the result of checking collisions turns out false?

Comment: If your box/swept-box check is false you're good to go, just move your box to where it wanted to go.  If it's true you need to figure out when during `dt` it became true.  I recommend a binary search where you vary your swept-box second point along (position+velocity*alpha), where alpha varies between 0.0 and 1.0.  When you find when your collision occurred you just set your box's final position to (position+velocity*alpha).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I already apply this method and works really great.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define speed? Let's just assume it's pixels per second, then in order to allow higher speeds you should check for collisions many times in a second. So in pseudocode:

```
double time = GetElapsedTime();
player.updatePosition(speed * time);
```

Now it's probably more complex then that, but you get the idea; either do something like this or use exact collision detection (I once found a great article but can't seem to find it) which uses equations to "predict" when and where objects will collide.

Answer (score 1):

One method I've used:

When moving a (player, other sprite…), determine all of the tiles through which it passes as a rectangle.

By way of example:

```
on tick:
   player-box = (player.x, player.y) - (player.x + player.width, player.y + player.height)
   player-delta.x = (player-speed.x × (now - last-updated))
   player-delta.y = (player-speed.y × (now - last-updated))
   player-end-box = player-box + player-delta
     { i.e. player-end-box = ( player-box.top-left.x + player-delta.x,
                               player-box.top-left.y + player-delta.y ) -
                             ( player-box.bottom-right.x + player-delta.x,
                               player-box.bottom-right.y + player-delta.y ) }
   player-collided = ( min (player-box.top-left.x, player-end-box.top-left.x),
                       min (player-box.top-left.y, player-end-box.top-left.y) ) -
                     ( max (player-box.bottom-right.x, player-end-box.bottom-right.x),
                       max (player-box.bottom-right.y, player-end-box.bottom-right.y) )
```

You can then take the `modulo 32` of each corner of `player-collided` to determine tiles that the player (or whatever sprite) has (attempted to) occlude.

Typically, you may want to put a small "margin" inset on the player's actual size to avoid 1px or 2px overlaps… (i.e. set the starting box to be smaller than the actual sprite by a few px), depending on how accurate your players' controls are, and the size difference between the sprite and one tile.

Note that very fast (many tiles per update) diagonal movements make this invalid, but it works well for very fast linear (horizontal or vertical) movement. If you're moving "too fast" on a diagonal, for this method, instead consider connecting the starting and ending rectangles into a polygon (irregular hexagon) and testing each tile for whether it contains any part of that hexagon.

```
  for each tile in (big rectangular area):
      if tile is inside polygon (hexagon of movement):
          add tile to list of collisions
```

This is essentially an optimization of full boundary-geometry checking for the common 2D cases.